# A function for returning a list of tuples that correspond to indices of ALL elements of an ndarray sorted?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I'm aware of `numpy.argsort()`, but what it does is return indices of elements in an array that would be sorted along a certain axis.

What I need is to sort *all* the values in an N-dimensional array and have a linear list of tuples as as result.

Like this:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> A = numpy.array([[7, 8], [9, 5]])
>>> numpy.magic(A)
[(1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1)]
```

P.S. I don't even understand what the output of argsort is trying to tell me for this array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.argsort(A)` is sorting each row of `A` separately. For example,

```
In [21]: np.argsort([[6,5,4],[3,2,1]])
Out[21]: 
array([[2, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 0]])
```

Instead, you want to flatten your array into a 1-dimensional array of values, then argsort that. That can be done by setting the `axis` parameter to `None` (thanks to @Akavall for pointing this out):

```
In [23]: np.argsort(A, axis=None)
Out[23]: array([3, 0, 1, 2])
```

Then use [np.unravel_index](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html#numpy-unravel-index) to recover the associated index in `A`.

---

```
In [14]: import numpy as np

In [15]: A = np.array([[7, 8], [9, 5]])   

In [4]: np.column_stack(np.unravel_index(np.argsort(A, axis=None)[::-1], A.shape))
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 0],
       [1, 1]])
```

Note, for NumPy version 1.5.1 or older, `np.unravel_index` raises a ValueError if passed an array-like object for its first argument. In that case, you could use a list comprehension:

```
In [17]: [np.unravel_index(p, A.shape) for p in np.argsort(A, axis=None)[::-1]]
Out[17]: [(1, 0), (0, 1), (0, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Comment: You can do `np.argsort(A, axis=None)` and skip the `ravel()` step.

Comment: @Akavall: Thanks very much for the improvement.

Comment: No need for the list comprehension, `np.unravel_index` will take an array of indices as first argument, somehting like `np.vstack(np.unravel_index(np.argsort(A, axis=None)[::-1], A.shape)).T` is more _numpythonic_.

Comment: @Jamie: Thanks for the improvement!